# Protect your Apache Server

Tags: apache2

I am a developer sites, I have an Apache server I want to be private and not open to me on the Internet to protect How do I do

Answer (score 1):

Broad question but I'll bite.

1. Firstly you could develop offline and upload when done. Do this on your home computer.
2. Secondly you could have it online but password protect access to the development sites using .htpassword and .htaccess (see below)
3. Thirdly you can have it online but set a firewall rule using iptables rule to only allow inbound http from a specific IP address or even MAC address

For .htaccess file that you'd do put this in the folder of the page you're protecting:

```
AuthUserFile /home/testsite/.htpasswd
AuthName "Test Site Login Area"
AuthType Basic

require user testsite
```

Then you'd create the htpasswd as so:

```
htpasswd -c /home/testsite/.htpasswd testsite
```

...Where you get prompted for a password.

Tutorial available here:
[htaccess and htpasswd tutorial](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html)

Lastly for the firewall rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT \! --src 1.2.3.4 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP  # if it's not 1.2.3.4, drop it
```

This is modified from the concept posted here, and there are more examples you can alter to suit your needs.

[iptables how to allow only one ip through specificport](https://serverfault.com/questions/146569/iptables-how-to-allow-only-one-ip-through-specific-port)